# Finding the Sum of Converging series when there is a range for $r$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

The problem is: what values of $x$ will cause the following series to converge:

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n (x+1)^n$

I wasn't sure how to determine x but just took a few moments of "*playing*" with the series to see what values would make for an $|r|\lt1$.  I could tell I needed $-\frac 12\lt(x+1)\lt\frac 12$.

So, I would like to know the proper process for this rather than me just "*playing with numbers*".

***Also, the next part of the problem said, find the sum of the series for those values of $x$.***
I'm really stuck on this because it appears they want ONE sum.  Even if they want more than one sum, seems like the sum would have a range of values.  I say this because with different values of $x$ I get various values of $r$, all of which are $\lt1$, making the series converge.  But for $n=0$, the first term is always $1$, so it appears to me that I get a different sum for the series depending on what value of $x$ I use.  And since $-1.5\lt x \lt -.5$, I can't use those values to evaluate the sum since it's *greater than* or *less than* not equal to.

Stuck here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple geometric series with common ratio $r=2(1+x)$. So it is convergent iff $|2(1+x)| <1$ or $-\frac  3 2 < x <-\frac 1  2$ and the sum  is $\frac  1 {1-r}=\frac 1 {1-2(1+x)} =-\frac 1  {1+2x}$.

Comment: totally clear now.  I'm feeling pretty bummed that I didn't see that.  I need more practice